# Is there any known way to create a cart item that doesn't exist as a product?

Tags: product, checkout, cart, quote

I'm going to be receiving product data from multiple 3rd-party sources in a common format.

Generally, I've seen this issue handled by either creating  a product for each incoming item in the user's cart from the 3rd-party, or loading all the relevant product data as json in a product's textbox custom option.

The first way can add a lot of bloat to the database, and the second can require updating a lot of templates to use the json data.

Is there a way to directly create quote items without a corresponding product existing? Or does anyone have a good starting point where I could override the existing functionality?

I'm poking around Mage/Checkout but not finding quite what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: A `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` has a required reference to a product, but you can edit everything. So if you ask me, have one product (maybe implement your own product type?) and implement a renderer for the product page and the cart. This should be a good start...

Comment: Did you found an answer? Please share it with us.

Comment: I just needed it for a proof of concept that hasn't turned into a real project yet, so I went with the approach of creating a new product since I knew I could get that done in the time allotted. I'll probably revisit this if the project pans out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your scenario, I would use a product setup just for adding these items to the quote/cart with custom information on it. After you create the quote item from the product programmatically, you can set custom pricing, "custom" custom options for displaying key/value information (no template mods) alongside it and you can even set a custom URL and image on the quote item.